# Writing to UniVerse Linked Server from SQL Server via ODBC

Tags: sql-server, universe, u2

I have an ODBC connection to UniVerse on AIX working well as a linked server on SQL Server to read data using OPENQUERY but have not been able to write back.

I can’t send a UniVerse SQL Native Update query via ODBC because OpenQuery expects returned data which I can’t provide in the same expression, as UniVerse ODBC only supports one command at a time.

I can issue a valid T-SQL Update command via the OPENQUERY syntax to either an ODBC or Native UniVerse Select but it won’t perform the update.

SQL Server is talking to UniVerse and UniVerse is happy with the syntax and permissions for updating.
I can tell it is negotiating because when introducing an invalid column name or wrong data type, UniVerse will respond with the expected error messages.

The deal falls over on the last hurdle when they have agreed over the negotiation and the update is commanded.

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "servername" returned message "Insufficient base table information for updating or refreshing."

I think this means UniVerse ODBC is not telling the provider that my DICT item, ID (or @ID, Universe’s default key which I also tried) is the Primary key of the table.

I'm hoping someone has succeeded another way or has any suggestions, however wild. It is frustrating to be apparently so close to success but so far away.

Comment: `I can’t send a UniVerse SQL Native Update query via ODBC because OpenQuery expects returned data which I can’t provide in the same expression, as UniVerse ODBC only supports one command at a time.` You know you don't have to use openquery. You can execute stuff at remote server like: `EXECUTE('update table set somevalue = ''something else''') at yourLinkedServer`

Comment: @siggemannen Thankyou so much. It worked. Your advice was exactly the kind of solution I was hoping to get. I didn't know the EXECUTE syntax because I had been Googling for Update. It only works with UniVerse SQL NATIVE syntax but that is not surprising.

Comment: Great, i'm adding it as an answer as well then!

Comment: btw, have you tried the four-part update? Like: `UPDATE server.database.schema.tableName SET somevalue = 'someothervalue'` ?

Comment: The four part update would require UniVerse accepting the ODBC update which is not working. That returns an error about being read only but I can't see anything limiting the permissions on the linked server. Only the full passthrough native Universe SQL command works. Clearly the permissions in AIX are fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried using a four part name in a select and the response indicated that UniVerse ODBC does not support four part naming at all.

Comment: Must be a really lazy driver, or perhaps the data underneath can't really translate well to sql. What error did you get?

Comment: It is acase of the ODBC not supporting the requirements. 

'Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServerName". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.'

The catalog shown under the linked server is nameless.

Answer (score 1):

For non-selects you can use the `EXECUTE(...) AT SERVER` syntax, something like:

```sql
EXECUTE('update table set somevalue = ''something else''') AT yourLinkedServer
```

You can read more info at [Microsoft remote query documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-openquery-openrowset-exec-at?view=sql-server-ver16)